# django model form fields = () behaviour

Tags: django, django-forms

What happens when I define a field in django forms like this:

```
class FooForm( ModelForm ):
  class Meta:
    model = FooModel
    fields = ( 'foo', 'bar', ) # I am talking about this field
```

When I have the fields **foo, bar and baz** in my models, what happens with baz then in this case?

Are these fields required or not automatically? are they just available? What is actually happening with that field when I am doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `fields = ('foo', 'bar',)`, the field `baz` does not exist at all in the form, unless you set it explicitly (`fields` only "fills in" the missing model fields). When you use `form.save()`, `baz` is not set to a value on the model either. If the field is required on your model, your code must ensure that it is set before the model is saved to the database.

It is entirely possible, and quite often necessary, to have a required field that's not in the form. E.g. when you have to relate your model to the current user, you can remove the `user` field from your form, and use:

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
obj.user = request.user
obj.save()
```

The important distinction here is that form fields are for user input, and model fields are for the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, it will determine if the fields are required from your FooModel, depending on the `null=True` and `blank=True`.

By default, model fields are required, so if they should not be required you have to let django know. Depending on the field type, to make a field not required you need to put `null=True` and/or `blank=True`.

More information can be found in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#null) on how django determines if a field is required or not based on the model.

Comment: Actually, only `blank=True` determines if a field is required in a derived form field. `null=True` determines if the field can be `NULL` in the database.

Comment: So if blank = True in my models, I don't need to specify it again in my modelform?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi Exactly. In the form it will be optional. For some fields (details in the docs link) you need to also mark null = True in the model, or you will have database errors.